# Fan keeps still running even after shutdown. must long press power button to stop it

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, fan

I have a problem with my PC on win7 64bit.
My specs: i7 3770k with a MB asus PZ77 V LE and a custom fan cooler master Hyper 212

I know that this is a recurring problem, but so far i was not able to spot the right solution

- everything works correctly, correct temperatures, etc
- when I    shut down the computer, win7 closes but the cooler
  master fan keeps    running forever and I am forced to long-press the
  power button to    shut it off.
- i tried to look into the bios settings but i did not    find
  anything...
- EDIT: i booted in safe mode and the PC does NOT shut off correcly: it
  freezes on the closing animation window and I need to long press the power button to shut it down
- EDIT: the disk where win7 is installed is a kingston ssd. i also have
  Intel Rapid Storage Technology that just crashes when I try to load
  it..

Do you have an idea?
Many, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Which fan (I'm guessing your cooler)? Where is it plugged in?

Comment: yes the Cooler Master fan on the CPU

Comment: Which fan port is it plugged into? Its still odd, but might help narrow things down

Comment: thank you for your help. how can i find the port?

Comment: Well, see where its plugged in, and read the teensy silkscreened print. It should be plugged into CPU fan, not CPU Alt, where where along the top/middle of your board

Comment: yes its CPU fan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be hardware and software issue either. It is really hard to debug what is wrong, some of the possible reasons: PSU failure, BIOS error, motherboard or graphics card driver bug, etc...

By me this was cause by windows update, because it automatically updated the graphics card driver to a newer unstable version. Once a week I had small screen distortions, that's how I knew where to look for the problem... I updated the driver to an even newer version manually, restarted the computer and the problem was solved...